# assign null default value for optional query param in route - Play Framework

Tags: java, routes, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to define an optional query parameter that will map to a `Long`, but will be `null` when it is not present in the URL:

```
GET  /foo  controller.Foo.index(id: Long ?= null)
```

... and I essentially want to check if it was passed in or not:

```
public static Result index(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {...}
    ...
}
```

However, I'm getting a compilation error:

> type mismatch; found : Null(null) required: Long Note that implicit
>   conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous: both method
>   Long2longNullConflict in class LowPriorityImplicits of type (x:
>   Null)Long and method Long2long in object Predef of type (x: Long)Long
>   are possible conversion functions from Null(null) to Long

Why can't I do this, assigning `null` to be a default value for an expected `Long` optional query parameter? What's an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remember that the optional query parameter in your route is of type `scala.Long`, not `java.lang.Long`. Scala's Long type is equivalent to Java's primitive `long`, and cannot be assigned a value of `null`.

Changing `id` to be of type `java.lang.Long` should fix the compilation error, and is perhaps the simplest way to resolve your issue:

```
GET  /foo  controller.Foo.index(id: java.lang.Long ?= null)
```

You could also try wrapping `id` in a Scala `Option`, seeing as this is the recommended way in Scala of handling optional values. However I don't think that Play will map an optional Scala Long to an optional Java Long (or vice versa). You'll either have to have a Java type in your route:

```
GET  /foo  controller.Foo.index(id: Option[java.lang.Long])

public static Result index(final Option<Long> id) {
    if (!id.isDefined()) {...}
    ...
}
```

Or a Scala type in your Java code:

```
GET  /foo  controller.Foo.index(id: Option[Long])

public static Result index(final Option<scala.Long> id) {
    if (!id.isDefined()) {...}
    ...
}
```

Comment: hey @avik... what would the method declaration look like for this `Option[Long]` thing...?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I use a String variable.

Example :

In my route :

`GET  /foo  controller.Foo.index(id: String ?= "")`

Then I convert in my code with a parser to Long --> Long.parseLong.

But I agree that the method of Hristo is the best.